# Is there a better alternative for using two $this-> in the same sentence?

Tags: php, class, object, this

If you do:

```
    $this->$this->name->something();
```

You will surely get an error.

I've been doing something like:

```
    $name =& $this->name;
    $this->$name->something();
```

But is there a better way for doing that? Would it be easier if PHP had some way of doing something like:

```
    $this->'$this->name'->something();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're doing, can't you just use `$this->name->something()`?

Comment: Do I get this right: You want to read out the name member of an object and use this a dynamic value for calling a method? Sounds like you should move this inside of $this->something().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there a better way for doing that? Would be easier, if PHP has some way to do, something like: $this->'$this->name'->something();

There is;

```
$this->{$this->name}->something( );
```

But... what are you doing? Do you really need this? It seems like an odd construct from where I'm standing.

Comment: Using in a controller that based on the URL instantiate a module and call a method. Since this param will be used across the class I set in the constructor $this->module = $valueFromUrl. And later I can use $this->{$this->module}->someMethod();

Answer (score 2):

If `$this->name` is an object, then `$this->name->something()` should work just fine.

Edit: Note also, if your methods return objects, you can just chain up the method calls:

```
$this->name->something()->somethingElse()->anotherThing();
```

Comment: last sample is called fluent interfaces. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface